# flashing my a3900 lenovo mobile

Tags: rom-flashing

please house help me I can't flash my lenovo a3900 phone because it can't connect to my Laptop using the usb cable and it keeps hanging and showing "no command" MY usb cable works perfectly.

Comment: You're in recovery mode - stock recovery to be exact - it's not supposed to be responding to anything in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide infos about the platform, I assume its the Mediatek version.

To flash this phone you'll need SP Flashtool and ROM file with scatter. You'll also need USB drivers which make it possible for your device to communicate with the computer. The phone needs to be connected in Preloader mode.

- Downloaded [SP Flashtool](https://spflashtool.com/)
- Download MTK [USB drivers](https://androidmtk.com/download-mtk-usb-all-drivers)
- Download the [Firmware](https://boycracked.com/2016/05/11/official-lenovo-a3900-stock-rom-firmware/)